# Changed from job that had a 401K, and the new one doesn't. How do I answer when filing?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira

There is a question on the tax form when filing that asks "eligible to participate in a 401K plan at work?" [Yes/No].  I contributed to my 401k up until March.  I then took a new job that does not offer a 401K, and rolled mine into an IRA.  I've now made 2,000 in contributions to my IRA and 2,200 to my Roth IRA.

How do I answer that question on the form (which impacts whether or not my IRA contributions are deductible or not) when its Yes and No?

Answer (score 7):

If you had a retirement plan at any time in 2013 you are considered covered by an plan.

**[Are You Covered by an Employer's Retirement Plan?](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Are-You-Covered-by-an-Employer%27s-Retirement-Plan%3F)**

> You’re covered by an employer retirement plan for a tax year if your
>   employer (or your spouse’s employer) has a:
>
> - Defined contribution plan (profit-sharing, 401(k), stock bonus and money purchase pension plan) and any contributions or forfeitures were
>     allocated to your account for the **plan year ending with or within the
>     tax year;**
> - IRA-based plan (SEP, SARSEP or SIMPLE IRA plan) and you had an amount contributed to your IRA for the plan year that ends with or
>     within the tax year; or
> - Defined benefit plan (pension plan that pays a retirement benefit spelled out in the plan) and you are eligible to participate for the
>     plan year ending with or within the tax year.
>
> Box 13 on the Form W-2 you receive from your employer should contain a
>   check in the “Retirement plan” box if you are covered. If you are
>   still not certain, check with your (or your spouse’s) employer.
>
> The limits on the amount you can deduct don’t affect the amount you
>   can contribute. However, you can never deduct more than you actually
>   contribute.
>
> Additional Resources:
>
> [Publication 590](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/index.html), Individual Retirement Arrangements (IRAs)

Comment: That sort of sucks.  Because I only contributed $500 into my 401K this year before leaving because I left after 1 pay cycle.  So by depositing once in it, negates my entire year of dumping into my IRA since 90% of the year I had NO access to a 401K, Pension, SEP, or employer sponsored IRA.  So now I won't be able 2 deduct my marginal tax rate on2000 deposited into my deductible IRA(~500). Thanks for the info though.  Doesn't seem fair that I sort of get penalized for going to a place that doesn't have a 401K from having access to one & not getting the benefit of IRA deposits for most of year.

Comment: @Mark: "So by depositing once in it," Even if you didn't contribute, the fact that you were covered is what matters.

Comment: @Mark I agree that this answer, while correct, sucks.  Consider contributing to a Roth if you are below the income limits.